# Creating or adding geometry colunm fails even with postgis enabled

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry-data-type

I'm trying to add a geometry colunm to a table in a database with postgis extention enabled (other tables in this schema even have geometry colunms), but it fails:

```
ALTER TABLE my_schema.my_table ADD COLUMN geom geometry(MultiPolygon, 4326);
```

gets me an error:

```
ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist
```

although

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

returns

```
ERROR:  extension "postgis" already exists
```

I'm running Postgres 9.5, but I cannot tell postgis verion because it throws another error

```
ERROR:  function postgis_full_version() does not exist
```

Although postgis is listed under extensions in pgadmin.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the platform and version of PostgreSQL, and the version of PostGIS.

Comment: If PostGIS is installed in a schema different than public, it has to be in your search path https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407622/postgis-not-available-for-all-postgres-users/48422325#48422325

Comment: @JGH you were right, I forgot that I changed search path earlier. Can you post it as an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PostGIS extension must be installed in a schema that must also be in the user search path.

You can check where it is installed with the command

```
select e.extname,n.* 
from pg_extension e, pg_namespace n 
where e.extnamespace = n.oid and e.extname='postgis';
```

And you can check if the schema where it is installed is in the user search path by issuing

```sql
show search_path;
```

If not, you can permanently add the path by altering the user.

```sql
ALTER USER username SET search_path TO "$user", public, postgis_schema;
```

As the previous command takes effect at the next login only, you can apply it immediately by applying

```sql
SET search_path TO "$user", public, postgis_schema;
```