# Type geometry does not exist PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry

I am trying to add a geometry column to an existing table in PostgreSQL inside a plpgsql function using

```
EXECUTE format('ALTER table %I add column geom geometry(Point, 102003)', target_table);
```

Its raising an error "type "geometry" does not exist".
[image]

There is PostGIS extension installed in the database which I am running. Only thing is my table are not in public schema.

Comment: can you edit this post to share the screenshot of error?

Comment: Don't you need to prefix the type with the schema if you choose other than `public`?

Comment: Or you have to open the SQL Query window from within the public schema ... that helps sometimes (in pgAdmin III)

Comment: it could be the search path https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284067/creating-or-adding-geometry-colunm-fails-even-with-postgis-enabled/284073#284073

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this issue by executing the following query in pgAdmin

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Already thats done and extension was created

Comment: perhaps there were some issues while creating postgis extension you need to drop postgis extension using "drop extension postgis" and re create it.

Comment: Well, i tried that too. Extension is getting created successfully

Comment: are you still getting the same error? I have tried the query you shared and it works fine. If you are still getting error you can use AddGeometryColumn function of postgis, you can refer to https://postgis.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html for further details