# Import Shapefile into PostGIS using DB Manger Plugin

Tags: postgis, shapefile, qgis-plugins

When I try to Import Shapefile into PostGIS using DB Manger Plugin in QGIS the error message show

```
"Error 3
Creation of data source "TEST_EST_MILION" failed: 
ERROR:  function addgeometrycolumn(unknown, unknown, unknown, integer, unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT AddGeometryColumn('','TEST_EST_MILION',NULL,32640,'MU...
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
"MU...
           ^
```

Comment: is PostGIS enabled in the DB? It is in the user path?

Comment: Do you mean the Connection ?

Comment: no, I am talking about the PostGIS extension. See [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284067/creating-or-adding-geometry-colunm-fails-even-with-postgis-enabled/284073#284073) for more details

Answer (score 2):

I don't use QGIS to import data but let me give you a working solution if you are able to use `ogr2ogr`.

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" "PG:host=serverhost user=username dbname=dbname password=password" yourshpfile.shp -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=the_geom -lco FID=gid -lco PRECISION=no -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI -nln tablename -t_srs "EPSG:4326"
```

Add your own credentials and set the SRID to your needs.
Add `-overwrite` if you want the layers to be erased on import.

Comment: Thank you.Where i can put this configuration . i am not familiar with this

Comment: @GIS_Q Well, as @JGH said in his comment above, before anything else check if PostGIS is enabled in the DB, sometimes people enable it globally and it doesn't work. If you are using PostgreSQL with the command line you can do it by connecting to the database with `postgres=# \c DBNAME` then `postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`